# How to show response from GET ajax call after user is offline through service worker?

Tags: service-worker, offline, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

Basically, I want my PWA to work offline. But on page load of website, there is an GET ajax call which helps in showing some content of the page.

Question is how do I let my PWA work offline as there will be an ajax call on page load which would require me to either store the response in cache?

As the content can be heavy, is it even correct to cache so much data?

Also, I read somewhere that we cannot cache GET requests, so how can I proceed with making PWA work offline?

I have tried looking at the following links, but these do not say me how to cache a dynamic content

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

https://vaadin.com/pwa/learn/caching-strategies

https://jslovers.com/dynamic-cache-serviceworkers.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can cache "dynamic" content – that's because from the browser's point of view it's just anothe HTTP request :-) It is of course a matter of your application & server logic whether that is useful in any way. For some application caching dynamic content and then showing it to the user at a later time might work completely ok but for some other application it might come with problems. You know, it would be fine to show a rarely updated avatar image but not ok to show old currency info, right?

You could also design the app around these limitations, maybe show the user a notification saying "hey, you're using an offline version and the data is XX hours old!" or something like that.

You can easily store multiple megabytes of network responses into the cache. If you've got more than 50 megs browsers start to limit you. Also, always have error handling ready if the browser tells you the cache is full or whatever.

Does this explanation help you?

Comment: Yes, sure the explanation does help. But I am caching the content using service worker and had a doubt that should I store it in Cache or IndexedDB? And even if I do cache, will the browser return response for the same in offline mode?